# How to close InputStream immediately?

Tags: java, concurrency, inputstream

There is an infinite input stream and I read incomming massages with following simple lines of code:

```java
InputStream inputStream = response.getBody();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
    while ((event = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // do the work
    } 
}
System.out.println("Connection closed");
```

And everything is fine. But I want to be able to drop the connection if a certain amount of time there is no new messages.

The first problem was that `readLine` method blocks execution until the next message receiving. That's what I want to avoid. And I found [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652999/interrupt-bufferedreaderreadline-without-closing-inputstream) of *CloasableReader* - wrapper over *Bufferedreader* that allows interrupting `readLine` from outside. So I just replaced *BufferedReader* with *CloasableReader* and *voalá* - I exited the while loop. But the line with "Connection closed" message still wasn't executed.

I changed the code a little bit...

```java
InputStream inputStream = response.getBody();
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    while ((event = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // do the work
    } 
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
System.out.println("Connection closed");
```

...and realized that actually `close` method also stucks waiting until next message receiving. Because of that Guava's `TimeLimiter::callWithTimeout` method didn't work for me. Actually it works fine (wrapping the code marked as "do the work" in the example above) but I cannot leave the try-catch-finaly block.

Internally `BufferedReader::close` calls `InputStreamReader::close` which calls `InputStream::close` and here is the problem. I'm just waiting and will do it forever.

I have no idea what to do now. How to force closing the stream?

Comment: The connection's **read-timeout** and [**connect-timeout**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) should have helped.

Comment: But how to access ```URLConnection``` object? I received ```ClientHttpResponse``` from ```RestTemplate::execute``` and I can get just ```InputStream```.

Comment: And also I don't want to close the connection a certain amount of time after opening but after receiving the last message.

Comment: what exception are you catching or declaring on the method? Both examples have `finally{}` but not `catch(){}`. If all you want to do is to execute that line with `System.out.println()` just place it in `finally{}` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825866/java-bufferedreader-hangs-forever-on-close-and-streamdecoder-doesnt-respect). You can try to find clues there about `callWithTimeout`.

If your input stream is from some socket, you can try the version without `callWithTimeout` and add `Socket.setSoTimeout`, so it will throw `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` when reading from InputStream after specified number of milliseconds.

**EDIT:** Since you're using `ClientHttpResponse`, you can set read and connect timeout like so

```java
    @Component
    public static class RestTemplateInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

        public static HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent e) {
            clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Yes, the same problem. And as I can see there is no solution. :/ ```callWithTimeout``` works with ```readLine``` method but cannot help me with closing.

Comment: @micobg I updated the answer with a way to set read and connect timeout for `ClientHttpResponse`

Comment: Setting the read timeout solved my problem. The only difference was that I pass the request factory to RestTemplate's constructor.